# tags: education/didactics vs learning/teaching

Tags: discussion, tags

I was confused a bit by [education](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education) and [didactics](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/didactics). Mainly, I guess, since I thought didactics is part of education.

Would it be better to change those tags to [learning-cs](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning-cs) and [teaching-cs](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching-cs) respectively? Or should these maybe only be synonyms?

Answer (score 2):

I think you summed up the difference between didactics and education aptly in your tag excerpt suggestions:

> *Education:* General questions regarding learning computer science disciplines and CS education
>
> *Didactics:* Didactic tools and methods particularly suitable for Computer Science education

I don't think a separation in "teaching" and "learning" is wise. Learning and teaching can often not be properly separated, in particular if you talk about education in the broader sense. Didactics is somewhat exclusive to teachers, although you can become a teacher quickly when explaining something to a colleague.

I also considered creating [intuition-building](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intuition-building) for certain kinds of questions but thought it was too unspecific.

Answer (score 0):

I propose we keep [education](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education) and get rid of [didactics](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/didactics) (e.g., mark it a synonym of [education](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education)).  I think the distinction between the two is too subtle and people won't know how to use them (and the current tag wikis don't help).

I looked through some questions tagged [didactics](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/didactics) and all of them seem like they could equally well be tagged [education](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education) (in fact, most of them already are tagged with both tags).  They certainly aren't currently used in a manner consistent with the distinction [Raphael proposed earlier](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/206/755), so even if we previously thought that distinction might be useful, I think experience over the past 4 years suggests that we were over-thinking it.  And, personally, today, I don't see enough value in the distinction, given how confusing the distinction is.

So, let's get rid of [didadics](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/didadics) and just use [education](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education).

Comment: My feeling is that we don't like most [tag:education] questions; they are often opinion-based or too broad, or should be on [academia.SE]. Or are really asking for didactics (many in the list of [tag:education] questions should be tagged didactics). I guess my point is that if your education question is not about how to explain/teach CS (i.e. didactics), it's probably not a good fit for the site.