# Wrapping up some tag discussions

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

There are a couple of old tag discussions that need resolving.

- [About the tag graph-algorithms](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1097/about-the-tag-graph-algorithms/)
- [Burninate tags: search-algorithms and search-problem](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287/burninate-tags-search-algorithms-and-search-problem)
- [Tags efficiency and performance](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1110/tags-efficiency-and-performance)
- [What about tags random and randomness?](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1099/what-about-tags-random-and-randomness)
- [Tags: network-flow, max-flow](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1030/tags-network-flow-max-flow)
- [software-verification vs program verification](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/385/software-verification-vs-program-verification)
- [About [recursion-theory]](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1325/about-recursion-theory)
- [Do we need both cluster and clustering tags?](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1294/do-we-need-both-cluster-and-clustering-tags)
- [Tags around partitions](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/tags-around-partitions?cb=1) (preemptively)
- [tags: education/didactics vs learning/teaching](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/205/tags-education-didactics-vs-learning-teaching)
- [What is the difference between the tags natural-lang-processing and computational-linguistics?](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/960/what-is-the-difference-between-the-tags-natural-lang-processing-and-computationa)

I'd like to get all of these dealt with by *September 7th*. 
**Please revisit the discussions and voice your opinion if it is not yet represented, and vote on the options that have been presented**.

(Please do not reply here to discuss a specific tag! Participate on the existing discussion. If you want to discuss other tags, create a new meta discussion.)

Answer (score 4):

#### Implemented on Sep 21, 2016

- [About the tag graph-algorithms](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1097/about-the-tag-graph-algorithms/)

  Create synonym [graphs](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphs) ← [graph-algorithms](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-algorithms) and add [algorithms](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithms) [if not already present](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-algorithms+-algorithms+-algorithm-analysis).
- [What about tags random and randomness?](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1099/what-about-tags-random-and-randomness)

  Create synonym. [randomness](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/randomness) ← [random](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random)
- [Tags: network-flow, max-flow](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1030/tags-network-flow-max-flow)

  Create synonym [network-flow](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/network-flow) ← [max-flow](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/max-flow).
- [Do we need both cluster and clustering tags?](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1294/do-we-need-both-cluster-and-clustering-tags)

  Create synonym [clustering](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clustering) ← [cluster](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cluster).
- [Tags around partitions](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/tags-around-partitions)

  Create synonym [partitions](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/partitions) ← [partition](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/partition).
  Create [integer-partitions](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer-partitions) and change [partitions](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/partitions) to is where appropriate.
  Add appropriate disambiguating tags to all [partition-problem](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/partition-problem), then create synonym [partitions](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/partitions) ← [partition-problem](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/partition-problem).
- [About [recursion-theory]](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1325/about-recursion-theory)

  Create synonym [computability](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computability) ← [recursion-theory](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recursion-theory).

#### Pending

- [Burninate tags: search-algorithms and search-problem](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287/burninate-tags-search-algorithms-and-search-problem)

  Create synonyms [searching](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/searching) ← [search-algorithm](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search-algorithm), [search](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search) and add [algorithms](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithms) [if not already present](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search-algorithms+-algorithms+-algorithm-analysis).

#### Deferred

There was not enough opion/voting data for these proposals.

- [tags: education/didactics vs learning/teaching](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/205/tags-education-didactics-vs-learning-teaching)
- [What is the difference between the tags natural-lang-processing and computational-linguistics?](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/960/what-is-the-difference-between-the-tags-natural-lang-processing-and-computationa)
- [software-verification vs program verification](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/385/software-verification-vs-program-verification)
- [Tags efficiency and performance](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1110/tags-efficiency-and-performance)
- [Remove [randomized-algorithms]](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1327/98)